# How to remove symbols from string and put them back?

Tags: java

Global task is to swap longest word with shortest word in text.
I need to remove symbols for example `,!.?` from text(to count length of word) and update array of words, do some logic and after put them back.

My solution:

```java
Map<Integer, String> idxToSymbolMap = new HashMap<>();

// remove symbols and save them to map
void deleteSymbols(String[] array) {
        String[] symbols = {POINT, QUESTION_MARK, EXCLAMATION_MARK, COMMA};
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (String s : symbols) {
                if (array[i].contains(s)) {
                    array[i] = array[i].replace(s, EMPTY_STRING);
                    idxToSymbolMap.put(i, s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
// some code here...

// add symbols back
void addBackSymbols(String[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int idx = i;
            idxToSymbolMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
                if (k == idx) {
                    array[idx] +=  v;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

How could I do that better, cleaner? Is possible using replaceAll or something else?

Comment: `words[idx] = words[idx] + value;` - this will append the symbol at the end. Not the position where it was replaced. Is that what you want?

Comment: As I think, its ok, because this symbols are always stay at the end of words, right? For example see my comment :)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454). What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: Can you put sample input and output in your question? I don't get what you're trying to do here.

Comment: input is `London is the capital of Great Britain, but Amsterdam of Netherlands.`
output is `London Netherlands the capital of Great Britain, but Amsterdam of is.`
the whole task is to swap first matched shortest word with longest

Comment: Put that in the question, please. It's important information that shouldn't be given in comments.

Comment: The question is about "How to remove symbols from string and place them back", not "how to switch shortest word with longest"

Comment: See the comment by Andreas. We can only help you if we understand what problem you are trying to solve. Reason: There might be an easier way (XY problem). So, please [edit] with something like "I need to solve ... problem. This is my approach:..."

Comment: @ModusTollens updated

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you have is the right approach, imo.

However, you can make it cleaner:

```
String[] symbols = {".", "?", "!", ","};
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (String s: symbols) {
        if (array[i].contains(s)) {
            array[i] = array[i].replace(s, "");
            idxToSymbolMap.put(i, s);
        }
    }
}
```

Or using java 8+:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(i ->
        Arrays.stream(symbols).filter(s -> array[i].contains(s)).forEach(s -> {
            idxToSymbolMap.put(i, s);
            array[i] = array[i].replace(s, "");
        }));
```

And replace it:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(
    idx -> idxToSymbolMap.keySet().stream().filter(key -> key == idx)
        .forEach(key -> array[idx] += idxToSymbolMap.get(key)));
```

Comment: Thank  you, but this examples are not working the same. First example swapped letters including symbol and left symbol on prev place(symbols copied) , second returned string with double comma, and third removed symbol from start place and added to new

Comment: My bad. I did not add the line of code to replace it! Works as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

`Map<String, List<Integer>>` will be the best fit for this requirement where the key is the symbol and value is the list of indices where the symbol exists in the text.

For the sake of testing, let's replace each occurrence of `[.,!?]` with `#`, print the replaced string and get back the original string.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, List<Integer>> symbolToIdxMap = new HashMap<>();

        // Test string
        String text = "abc .123,  xyz! hello . hi";

        // Regex pattern
        String strPattern = "[\\.\\,\\!\\?]";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int index;

        // Store the symbols and their indices in the map
        while (matcher.find()) {
            // Index at which any of [.,!?] is found
            index = matcher.start();

            // Character at `index`
            Character symbol = text.charAt(index);

            // If the List<Integer> for `symbol` exists, get it return a new
            // ArrayList<Integer> to `idxList`
            List<Integer> idxList = symbolToIdxMap.getOrDefault(symbol, new ArrayList<Integer>());

            // Add `index` to `idxList`
            idxList.add(index);

            // Put `idxList` as the value of `symbol`
            symbolToIdxMap.put(symbol, idxList);
        }

        // Replace the symbols in the text
        String replaced = text.replaceAll(strPattern, "#");
        System.out.println("Replaced: " + replaced);

        // Restore original string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(replaced);
        for (Entry<Character, List<Integer>> entry : symbolToIdxMap.entrySet()) {
            // Replace the character at all indices in the list with the corresponding
            // character
            for (Integer idx : entry.getValue()) {
                sb.setCharAt(idx, entry.getKey());
            }
        }

        // Display original string
        System.out.println("Original: " + sb);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Replaced: abc #123#  xyz# hello # hi
Original: abc .123,  xyz! hello . hi
```

Comment: A comment here from OP says they need to count characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544270/how-to-remove-symbols-from-string-and-put-them-back/62544527?noredirect=1#comment110607687_62544423

Comment: The count of every symbol in the question is already there in the map. You just need to get the size of the value e.g. `System.out.println(symbolToIdxMap.get(Character.valueOf('.')).size());`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I mean I need to count length of every string element(word without symbols) in array:)